# Draw pie chart in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-plot, pie-chart

I am new to iPhone,

I want to draw Pie chart in my iPhone app,

After lot of searching i found this [Tutorial...](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application)

when i download this code and try to run i am getting `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h file not found`
you can see in my snapshot `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h` file is present still it is showing error.

[image: 1]
**Any help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the header search path in your app project. Make sure it points to the right directory and is set to "recursive". There is more information on the [Core Plot wiki](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications).

Comment: I had written this `/Users/krunal/Desktop/CorePlotTest/CorePlot_1.0/Source/framework` in my `header search path` Still it is not working.. Do i need to change path ?

Comment: That should be ok. Make sure it's set to "recursive".

Answer (score 1):

[Download this project](https://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library) and use this but they are using ARC for that. Hope it will help you!

there you will find Pie Chart ,Line Chart,Bar Chart Etc.

Answer (score 1):

try this [link](https://github.com/tylerneylon/moriarty) , use `BNPieChart` to draw chart

Call this method to view example.

```
[BNPieChart pieChartSampleWithFrame:frame]
```